# What does it imply when someone addresses someone else with the phrase “you of all people”?

Tags: phrases, usage

Consider a situation in which two individuals are talking — person A and person B. In the conversation, A addresses B with the phrase:

> “you of all people”.

What does the phrase “you of all people” imply here, and what is its proper usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an idiom phrase: "***of all people***",

> **of all people** 
> <sub>idiom</sub>
>
> — used to emphasize that a specified person is the person one most or least expects to do or know something
> // *You, of all people, should know the answer to this.*
> // *My best friend, of all people, betrayed me.*
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20all%20people#:%7E:text=%E2%80%94used%20to%20emphasize%20that%20a,of%20all%20people%2C%20betrayed%20me.))

> used to show that you are especially surprised at a particular person's behaviour because it does not seem typical of them:
>
> *I thought that you, of all people, would believe me!*
>
> ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of-all-people))

Note that it doesn't always have to be "people"; it can also be, say, "[places](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+all+people%2fplaces%2fthings)" or "[things](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+all+people%2fplaces%2fthings)".

Example sentences (from The Free Dictionary)

with "people":

- *Really, Jeff, **you of all people** should know that it is never OK to get behind the wheel after drinking.*
- *And then Tom Hanks, **of all people**, stopped by to take pictures with our wedding party in the park.*

with "places":

- *If it's a rest they need, then why go to New York **of all places**?*
- *My parents are taking us to Louisiana, **of all places**. What the heck is there to do in Louisiana?*

with "things":

- *When he retired, he took up painting, **of all things**. He had never even picked up a paintbrush before that!*
- *After spending his childhood in and out of detention centers, he became, **of all things**, a cop.*

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, have a nice day.